# How to get most recent commented post above new submitted post in Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, comments, posts

I have this function:

```
$ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT comment_post_ID
FROM $wpdb->comments
ORDER BY comment_date DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30");

foreach ($ids as $id) {
  $post = &get_post( $id );
  setup_postdata($post); ?>
  <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Which shows the `latest commented posts` in a list, which is fine. What I want to do is give a priority to this one and combine it with a "`get newest post list`". So let's say I commented today on a post called Hello World and someone else submitted a post yesterday... Than I want to get the recent commented post above this new post. The problem is that in my code snippet, there is nothing that says to get the newest posts. How can I **combine** them? **So how to combine most recent commented posts and newest posts with each other?** Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try works perfect for me what it is doing query get the all the posts with a `left jon` with `comments` table so when  a post has comment them=n it also has the `comment_date` if no comments posted on the post then in result set it will be `null` so i have merged the `comment_date` with `post_date` so which post has the greater date (for comment_date or post_date) it will first and so on

```
SELECT p.*,
(CASE WHEN c.comment_date IS NULL THEN p.`post_date` ELSE c.comment_date END) order_column
 FROM `wp_posts` p
LEFT  JOIN `wp_comments` c  ON (p.ID = c.`comment_post_ID` ) WHERE p.post_type='post' AND p.post_status='publish'
GROUP BY p.ID
 ORDER BY order_column   DESC
```

For displaying the posts you have to first get the results by defining the WP's global variable for the database interaction i.e `$wpdb`

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("    SELECT p.*,
    (CASE WHEN c.comment_date IS NULL THEN p.`post_date` ELSE c.comment_date END) order_column
     FROM `wp_posts` p
    LEFT  JOIN `wp_comments` c  ON (p.ID = c.`comment_post_ID` ) WHERE p.post_type='post' AND p.post_status='publish'
    GROUP BY p.ID
     ORDER BY order_column   DESC"); 
?>
```

HTML

```
<?php foreach($results as $result){

<h1><?php echo $result->post_title;?></h1>
<div> <?php echo $result->post_content;?> </div>
// and so on the fields of wp_posts
<?php } // loop end ?>
```

Hope that is what you were looking for

Comment: Thanks Dianuj, it looks like this will going to work. Can I ask what the HTML is? I am a noob in MYSQL...

Comment: See my answer at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105534/how-to-get-most-recent-commented-post-above-new-submitted-post-in-wordpress/105535#105535

Comment: @ Dianuj Can I ask you a related question about this problem? If  you have already commented on the post, it won't put the post after the second or third comment above. It only does that once... Is there a workaround for this problem?

If you want, I can make a new topic about this question.

Comment: @Johan Yes sure please make a new question and add all the brief and send me the link also

Comment: @ Dianuj thanks my brother, here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725112/most-recent-post-does-not-come-above-post-if-there-was-already-made-an-comment