# Most recent post does not come above post if there was already made an comment

Tags: wordpress, post, comments, posts

@Dianuj solved my issue a week ago, when I asked how I can get a `recent comment` above a `post`. That all worked very well, but yesterday, when I tested it, I saw a little issue, which I not want on my `Wordpress` site. Let me explain it to you...

If someone makes a comment on a post that has none comments before you comment, then the function on this page [How to get most recent commented post above new submitted post in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501490/how-to-get-most-recent-commented-post-above-new-submitted-post-in-wordpress) will work flawlessly. I thank Dianuj for making my life easier.

**The problem starts when a user makes a comment on a post that ALREADY has a comment in it. So for instance, you make the second comment on a post. In that case, the post title won't go up and show 'his' face on the page**. That is the big problem and I hope someone can help me out with the snippets that are on this link [How to get most recent commented post above new submitted post in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501490/how-to-get-most-recent-commented-post-above-new-submitted-post-in-wordpress)

PS: for the lazy ones, here it goes -->

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("    SELECT p.*,
    (CASE WHEN c.comment_date IS NULL THEN p.`post_date` ELSE c.comment_date END) order_column
     FROM `wp_posts` p
    LEFT  JOIN `wp_comments` c  ON (p.ID = c.`comment_post_ID` ) WHERE p.post_type='post' AND p.post_status='publish'
    GROUP BY p.ID
     ORDER BY order_column   DESC"); 
?>
```

Comment: its working fine the **post with a recent comment will comes up** no matters that post have many comments or a single

Comment: Well, it does not work for me like that, dianuj. I tested it multiple times and it is too bad that it does not work like I want it to be...

If there is already a comment, it won't put the post title above...

Edit: I tested it again, and as said, it does not get the post title above if there is already a comment. I can give you a link to test if you want (via Skype). There you can test it by yourself brother.

Comment: @dianuj can you add me on Skype please? See my profile.

Comment: add me on skype my id is dianuj89

Comment: I have added you on Skype. Let's hope we can solve this issue today :D

Comment: BTW: I am very close solving it. Need your help for the finishing touch. I am now getting recent commented posts above the posts, but it now shows me duplicate titles. If you come on Skype, we can finish it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In above case `GROUP BY` groups the data with first occurrence of the `p.ID` so the latest will be neglected here is the trick to get all data with the `ORDER BY` and then group the data so the latest one will be there

Try this one

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT   p.*,
       (CASE WHEN c.comment_date IS NULL THEN p.`post_date` ELSE c.comment_date END) AS order_column
     FROM `wp_posts` p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `wp_comments` c  ON (p.ID = c.`comment_post_ID` ) WHERE p.post_type='post' AND p.post_status='publish' 
     ORDER BY order_column DESC 
   ) t GROUP BY ID  ORDER BY order_column DESC
```

Comment: FANTASTIC! Dianuj is a hero. Thanks mate